# How to build an up-counter in Verilog

Tags: verilog

I have a problem with designing an up-counter. I am trying to implement a Single-cycle MIPS with Verilog, so I am trying to implement a Program counter.

I just need the main idea about how to built a counter and test it. I am new to Verilog, so I don't know where I've gone wrong.

---

This is my `counter.v`:

```
module PC (Clk, CLR, Q); 
   input Clk, CLR; 
   output [31:0] Q; 
   reg    [31:0] tmp; 

   always @(posedge Clk or posedge CLR) 
        begin 
        if (CLR) 
            tmp = 4'b0000; 
        else  
            tmp = tmp + 1'b1; 
        end
    assign Q = tmp; 
endmodule
```

And this is my testbench file:

```
define DELAY 20
module PC_testbench ();
reg clk  ;
reg clr ;
wire [31:0] q;
PC exec ( clk , clr , q );

initial clk = 0;
initial clr = 0;

initial begin 

clk=~clk;

#`DELAY; 

clk=~clk;

#`DELAY; 

clk=~clk;

#`DELAY; 

clk=~clk;



end 

initial begin
$monitor("clk = %b pc_next = %b  ",clk , q );
end 


endmodule
```

I got 32 x's as my result. Any ideas?

This is my result:

```
# clk = 1 pc_next = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  
# clk = 0 pc_next = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  
# clk = 1 pc_next = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  
# clk = 0 pc_next = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that counter `tmp` is initially 32'bx, and it needs to see a rising edge of `CLR` or be 1 during a rising edge of `Clk`before being reset to 32'b0.